# how to create the pdf file

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, pdf

how could be create the Pdf file by using php. i want a pdf file for the one page no need for number of page and every information should .is there any way for creating the one page

Comment: There are libraries available to perform this task. You can read [here](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/PHP/Use-PHP-to-Create-Dynamic-pdf-Files/).

Comment: The following post lists a wide range of HTML to PDF converters: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3178448/264628

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the already mentioned FPDF, there is also [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/). Have a look at their [examples](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php).

Answer (score 0):

I warmly recommend the [Fpdf class](http://www.fpdf.org/), I have used it before and it is really simple to use, and it comes with some easy to understand tutorials.

Creating a simple page is as simple as

```
$pdf=new FPDF();

$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);

$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');

$pdf->Output();
```

(taken from it's first tutorial)